# I am having issues using multiple nested master pages

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

I have a masterpage with a banner and 5 links below the banner, when I click on one of the links it opens up my child page that has 4 link buttons.

I made a nested page from the childpage but when I look at the nested child of the child of the parent, its empty and i can't add anything to it, no contenplaceholders or div tags.
My objective is when I click a link from the childmaster that I need the other nested master page to show up with forms in it and for the life of me I can't seem to get the logic correct.

Here's a rundown of the links..

The links on the master page are

```
Landfill, Facilities, marinas, parks and trails and fleet.
```

when the user clicks on i.e `facilities`, the facilities child page appears with 4 links that are tied to the facilities and they are:

```
Assets, elements, events and gridview.
```

When the user clicks on i.e., Assets I need to call another nested page that will contain the forms.
So I need to make another nested masterpage to the facilities masterpage.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do what I need so any ideas and all help is greatly appreciated.
I'm at a stand still until I get this figured out and I been trying to figure it out for the last few hours.

Thanks

Comment: Well that looks better and more clearer to read and understand

Comment: It's difficult to follow along here, can you provide more context for the audience?

Comment: @NicholasV. ? Forgive me, but i do not understand what you mean by providing more context

Comment: Sorry - What I mean is that it's hard to envision all that you describe here. Do you have any sort of visual aids

Comment: Visual aids? no. I completely understand what you meant now...I can make screen shots but i don't know how to attach the pics...I have figured out using a masterpage and a child masterpage, that was pretty simple. I did create another masterpage and connected it to my childmaster page but i cannot add anything to the child of the child

Comment: i was initially just going to use iframes to do all this but i was told using iframes would break my code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. On my child page i was missing a contentplaceholder.